# PythonにおけるCUDAを利用したGPU制御について

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, gpu

PythonにてTensorflow-gpuを利用したいと思い、CUDA ToolkitやcuDNNのインストールを行い、GPUを用いてプログラムを実行できていることを確認しました。

私のPCには、GPUが2台搭載されており、使用するGPUを指定したいと思っています。
プログラム内で具体的に

```
with tf.device(～):
```

と記述することで、使用するGPUを指定できることは確認しました。

それとは別に，プログラム実行時に、コマンドプロンプト上で

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python ～.py
```

とすることで使用するGPUを制限できるというのを見かけました。
幾つかのWebサイトを見たのですが、上記のコマンドを実行すると

```
'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

と言われます。どうすればこのコマンドが使用できるようになりますか？
PCのシステム面への知識不足だとは思うのですが、よろしくお願いします...

---

実行環境 : Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

参考にされた実行方法はLinux環境向けのコマンドですが、あなたが実際に実行しているのは恐らく
Windows環境のように見えるので、以下の情報を参考にシステムの環境変数を設定してみてください。

http://www.e-em.co.jp/gpu/setup.htm

> 2.4 グラフィックスボードのデバイス番号
>
> (3) 環境変数 CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES
>
> Windowsの[設定]→[システム]→[バージョン情報]→[システム情報]→[システムの詳細設定]を起動し、
>   [詳細設定]タブの[環境変数]をクリックし、[システム環境変数]の[新規]をクリックし、
>   [変数名]に"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"、[変数値]に以下のような適当な数値を入力してください。
>
> - 0 : デバイス番号0のみを計算に使用する。
> - 1 : デバイス番号1のみを計算に使用する。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
おっしゃる通り、私の実行環境はWindows8.1 です。
説明不足ですみません。

載せていただいたように、システム環境変数に"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"を追加し、値を1に設定してみましたが、結果は変わらずです。
"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"に値が設定できたことはコマンドプロンプト上で
"%CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES%"とすると"1"と表示されたことで確認できました。
しかし、この状態でpyファイルを実行しても、デフォルトのGPU-0が使用されてしまいました。

もちろん、
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python ～.py
も実行できませんでした...

Comment: 環境変数の設定を変更した後は、PCを再起動してみてください。

Comment: 再起動しても結果は変わらずでした...(TT)

Comment: 勘違いでした！先ほど載せていただいたWebサイトに「CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1」とした場合は、GPU-1がGPU-0として扱われるとの記述がありました。上手くGPUを変更できているにもかかわらず気づいていなかっただけのようでした。回答本当にありがとうございました！